# Android NDK: glReadPixels hangs on Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

I have a strange problem which only seems to occur on Samsung Galaxy S running Android version 2.2.2. The app hangs when executing the code below on the Galaxy S, but there is no problem running it on a Galaxy Tab 7 running Android 2.2 or a Tab 10.1, or even on a Nexus S running Android 2.3.6.

Here is the code in question:

```
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, offscreenFBO);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pDst);
```

The app hangs at `glReadPixels()`.
However, if I use a normal frame buffer instead of an offscreen buffer in `glBindFramebufferOES()`, the problem is not observed.

Did anybody run into a similar problem?

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem right now. Have you found the reason or any workaound to solve this? It's driving me crazy. Ih hangs my device, I have to remove the battery to get it working again. I'm on Android 2.3.3.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any way to work around this problem. I basically just gave up on the Galaxy S.

Comment: I guess I'll just do the same, though it really worries me since it's my only test device. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use Samsung's Remote Test Lab to test your app on actual devices over the internet. It's not totally robust, meaning that the connection to the device is sometimes lost or the device stops responding for no obvious reason, but it's free to use after you register and lets you try your app on a good variety of Samsung devices. http://rtl.innovator.samsungmobile.com